# How to know what is the service launched on raspbian startup?

Tags: boot, operating-systems, jessie-lite, raspbian-lite

I want to achieve instant startup, roughly 1 sec, by disabling unwanted startup services in my pi.

During the boot up, the cmd shows things like CUPS printing service, samba, dhcpcd ... etc. I don't want to uninstall them but delay the start up of these services for like 5 to 15 secs.

In my case, I only wanted the x to be started and capable to run python3.
Any thing I'll need to disable in order to achieve the targeted 1 sec boot up?
I have no idea what are the services that would be triggered during start up. Anyone can help in pointing me some directions?

Comment: I'm pretty certain you can't boot in X on a Raspberry Pi (or any other common computer platform) in 1 second.

Comment: Well, it's a target, so basically what I'm trying to do is to minimize the overall initialize time before boot into raspbian system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `systemd-analyze blame`. It shows you all the services that affect the boot time.

This [article](https://www.tecmint.com/manage-services-using-systemd-and-systemctl-in-linux/) is very useful for your purpose

Comment: Hey mate, thanks a lot ! You'd enlighten me in this part